# equivalence of definitions

Tags: probability-theory

Why are both definitions equivalent?

Random variable $X $ is called Infinite divisible if for each $n \in N $ there exist iid random variables $X_1,\dots X_n $ such that $X=\frac1n \sum X_i$ or the same without $\frac1n $. The latter is the one I am familiar with. 
for example if  $X\sim poisson (\lambda) $ then we can pick $ X_i \sim poisson (\lambda /n) $ but with the other definition it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can find $X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ such that $X=\frac{1}{n}\sum X_i$ then we can simply choose $Y_i=X_i/n$ and we have $X=\sum Y_i$.

One can do something analogous in the other direction.

So both definitions are equivalent.

Comment: but what would be $X_i $ in my case if X is poison distributed. I am only able to find the distribution of $ X_i /n $ but not $X_i $

Comment: or is it not possible to find the distribution of $X_i$ but only the distribution of $X_i/n $

Comment: the $X_i$ would be $\frac{1}{n}poisson(\lambda/n)$

Comment: if you know the distribution of random variable $X$ then you can find the distribution of $\frac{1}{n}X$ rather easily.